# How can I optimize this python exercise?

Tags: python, optimization

I would like to optimize the execution speed of a python exercise:
A list of position is given, the cursor moves between them. The objective is to find how many time was covered the most covered segment.
In my example [5, 3, 4, 3, 1, 6] the solution is 4.
[image: Segment example]

The result is good, but with more numbers to analyse, it's too long.
Here is my code:

```
liste = [5, 3, 4, 3, 1, 6]
nbPositions = len(liste)
listef = [0]*(nbPositions-1)
for i in range(nbPositions-1):
    valeur1 = liste[i]
    valeur2 = liste[i+1]
    if valeur1 < valeur2:
        for e in range(valeur1, valeur2, 1):
            listef[e-1] += 1
    else:
        for e in range(valeur1, valeur2, -1):
            listef[e-2] += 1
print(max(listef))
```

**Edit:** Thanks to [@Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67950166/) help, here is a version with another approach (it could probably be shorter, but it works):

```
liste = [5, 3, 4, 3, 1, 6]
nbPositions = len(liste)
liste_i = []
for i in range(nbPositions-1):
    liste_i.append(liste[i:i+2])
for i in range(len(liste_i)):
    if liste_i[i][1] < liste_i[i][0]:
        liste_i[i][1], liste_i[i][0] = liste_i[i][0], liste_i[i][1]
# or 
# liste_i = [itm if itm[0] < itm[1] else [itm[1], itm[0]] for itm in liste_i]
# but speed seems the same
liste_i.sort()
remplacement = {}
for i in range(len(liste_i)):
    if not str(liste_i[i]) in remplacement:
        prem = liste_i[i][0]
        deux = liste_i[i][1]
        diff = deux-prem
        if diff > 1:
            rempl = []
            for j in range(diff):
                rempl.append([prem+j, prem+j+1])
            remplacement[str(liste_i[i])] = rempl
list3 = []
for i in range(len(liste_i)):
    if str(liste_i[i]) in remplacement:
        list3.extend(remplacement[str(liste_i[i])])
    else:
        list3.append(liste_i[i])
plus = max(list3, key=list3.count)
print(list3.count(plus))
```

Comment: Why can you use `nbPositions = len(liste)`? Is `[1, 17, 13]` not a valid input? I think it would help if you described the actual task a bit better. The optimal solution here depends a bit on what assumptions can be made about the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: you made a good, brute-force attack on the problem.  Now, let's analyze this from a different standpoint.

- The direction of travel is irrelevant
- The order of travel is irrelevant

Instead of looking at the problem in the order of travel, look at it from the positions.  First, flip the endpoints of the segments so that they all go in the same direction.  Second, sort them in order.

```
1 3
1 6
3 4
3 4
3 5
```

Now, all you have to do is to count from left to right, seeing how many travel segments use that position.  Add one when the position appears in the left column; subtract one when it appears in the right.  There are plenty of ways to do this; I'm sure you can do the coding.  Your result should be like this:

```
Seg.   Use
1-2     2  (+2)
2-3     2
3-4     4  (+3, -1)
4-5     2  (-2)
5-6     1  (-1)
```

See how that works?  It's basic interval algebra.

---

This is part of the "bag of tricks" one picks up after programming for a while.  I recognized the problem as isomorphic to counting parentheses nesting.  When I was first programming in LISP, my girlfriend taught me to check balance by the simple tactic of counting the nesting level, such as:

```
 0 1    2    3         2 3         210
   (not (and (numberp a) (numberp b)))
```

You have to end the statement with a count of 0, or the parentheses are out of balance.

Each of your movement segments can be seen as a parenthesis pair.  Although not nested int he classing way (innermost pairing), the task is still to determine the maximum nesting level.  Your input then becomes:

```
pos:      1    2    3    4    5    6
paren:    ((      )(((   ))   )    )
```

Comment: Indeed, this approach is clever, thanks! I updated the question accordingly.